# Is it possible to use "this" in c++ to create local object in member function?

Tags: c++, this

I have a question regarding "this" keyword. I have a class called "BiPoly", which represents bivariate polynomial. There is a member function called `BiPoly<NT>::DifferentiateX()`, which gets Partial Differentiation wrt X, and it's self-modified.

```
template <class NT>
BiPoly<NT> & BiPoly<NT>::differentiateX() { 
    if (ydeg >= 0)
      for (int i=0; i<=ydeg; i++) 
    coeffX[i].differentiate();

    return *this;
}//partial differentiation wrt X
```

In another member function called BiPoly::eval1(), I need to get the result of `DifferentiateX()` of the object who calls `BiPoly<NT>::eval1()`. Since DifferentiateX() is self-modified, I have to create a temp variable to get the result within eval1(). My question is: can I use `"this"` to create a temp object within member function? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use copy constructor on `*this`, yielding a copy of your polynomial object which you then differentiate and evaluate:

```
BiPoly<NT> copy(*this);
copy.DifferentiateX();
NT val = copy.eval1(arg);
```

Depending on how do you store the coefficients (e.g. in standard `vector`), you might not even need to actually write the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should not return reference to temporary object that was created inside your function. It will be destroyed on function exit.

You'd rather declare your function as this:

```
template <class NT>
BiPoly<NT> BiPoly<NT>::differentiateX() { 
    BiPoly nv = *this;     
    if (nv.ydeg >= 0)
      for (int i=0; i<=nv.ydeg; i++) 
    nv.coeffX[i].differentiate();

    return nv;
}//partial differentiation wrt X
```

Note it returns object (copy of nv) but not reference to it.

Comment: His definition of `differentiateX` function is totally fine. It's not returning the reference to temporary object, but `*this` - the very object the method was invoked upon. Of course it can then be used to do stuff like `return BiPoly<NT>().differentiateX();` but that would be the problem with code that calls the method like that, not the method itself.

Comment: To Xion: yeah, just realized that his question was "can I use "this" to create a temp object within member function". Then the answer is still valid somehow: `BiPoly nv = *this;` is the way of declaring such temp variable with initialization using this object.